# Converting Frames to DIV

Tags: html

Just a little help. Is it possible to convert those Frames to DIV? Would you just give me some clue how to do it?

For instance, how could I convert Frame Left into DIV?

```
<frameset border="0" frameSpacing="0" borderColor="#336699" rows="14,88" frameBorder="0" onkeydown="KeyPressed();">
<frame name="Top" src="Header.aspx" scrolling="no">
<frameset border="0" frameSpacing="borderColor=#336699" frameBorder="NO" cols="17,83">
<frame name="Left" src="menu.aspx" scrolling="auto" width="100%">
<frame name="Right" src="Page1.aspx" >
</frameset>
<noframes>
</noframes>
</frameset>
```

Comment: First step is to try something. What have you got so far? Have you learned about CSS yet (hint, hint)?

Comment: ... for instance, jsfiddle would help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with jQuery (or straight up javascript). Have a look at the .load() function:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

If you had some div with ID "result", you could load what's currently serving as a source of a given frame contents into that div:

```
$('#result').load('Page1.aspx');
```

... by the same token you could load just a fragment of a given page as well.